# How to reverse css keyfrmames animation by only using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

```js
document.querySelector(".fall").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.querySelector(".ball").style.animation = "anim 2s forwards";
});

//my try below
document.querySelector(".up").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.querySelector(".ball").style.animation = "anim 2s forwards reverse";
});
```

```css
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
button{
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.box{
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: royalblue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
.ball{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
@keyframes anim {
    100%{
        top: 80px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ball"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <button class="fall">Fall ↓</button>
    <button class="up">Up ↑</button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wnna jump up **smoothly** this red ball by cliking **Up ↑** button after clicking **Fall ↓** button. I tride it by setting animation property with extra **reverse** but it's not working. It's jumping up suddenly. How can i achieve **smooth jumping up transition** by using **only** **keyframes** and **javascript**.

Comment: Do you want it to switch during the animation from falling to ascending? Or is it OK if the animation just "restarts" when clicking on either button?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my quick solution.

The animation was removed by setting `animation` as `""` in [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationend_event) event listener.

The `ball`'s `top` position is also set when related event listener is triggered.

```js
const ball = document.querySelector(".ball");
const fallButton = document.querySelector(".fall");
const upButton = document.querySelector(".up");

fallButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  ball.style.animation = "anim 2s forwards";

  ball.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    ball.style.top = "80px";
    ball.style.animation = "";
  });
});

upButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  ball.style.top = 0;
  ball.style.animation = "anim 2s forwards reverse";

  ball.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    ball.style.top = 0;
    ball.style.animation = "";
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: royalblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

.ball {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

@keyframes anim {
  100% {
    top: 80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ball"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <button class="fall">Fall ↓</button>
  <button class="up">Up ↑</button>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: **ball.style.top = "80px";** it's a very bad idea. Think about there is more than 50+ property in **anim** ,will you write like this then?

Comment: You can use CSS variable and change it with JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#values_in_javascript